# Retrieving msi package from azure blob storage using memory stream results in invalid file

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, memorystream

I have a method that returns an msi package using a filestream.

```
public FileStream DownloadMsiFileStream()
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\test.msi", FileMode.Create,    System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite);

        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("deviceupdate");

        // Retrieve reference to a blob named "KC.AttendanceManager.PrintServiceInstaller.msi".
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("test.msi");

        //Retrive the memorystream
        blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fs);

        return fs;
   }
```

This works just perfectly, I can download the filestream using a web api method, write the stream to a file and end up with a working msi package.

But now i want to avoid writing the file to disk on serverside as it results in concurrency issues. Instead i have tried changing the filestream to a Memorystream like this:

```
 public MemoryStream DownloadMsi()
        {

            // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("deviceupdate");

            // Retrieve reference to a blob named "KC.AttendanceManager.PrintServiceInstaller.msi".
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("test.msi");

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            //Retrive the memorystream
            blockBlob.DownloadToStream(ms);

            return ms;
        }
```

But when I am trying to write the stream to a file later on (just server side to get it working) like this:

```
MemoryStream ms = DeviceUpdateManager.GetClientUpdateMsi();
FileStream file = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\test2.msi", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
                file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
                ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
                file.Close();
                ms.Close();
```

The result is an invalid (empty) msi file. The memorystream is not empty as `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray())` returns a bunch. How do I end up with a working msi? Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

As often the solution is all too simple. This was all I needed to retrieve my working msi package:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\temp\test2.msi", ms.ToArray());
```